# General term of $a_n=a_{n-1}+\frac{1}{a_{n-1}}.$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let $a_n=a_{n-1}+\frac{1}{a_{n-1}}$ for $n > 1$ and $a_{1}= 1,$ find $a_{75}.$

I tried to solve this question by forming multiple combinations a new series $b_{n}$ having $a_{n-1}$ and $a_{n}$ in difference, hoping it would give me some solvable series of $b_{n}$ but did not got anything useful. Also tried solving quadratic of $a_{n-1}$ but still no results. Tried forming a telescopic series from terms but couldn't get to answer.
Help me to approach this question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can find some information by calculating a few terms and entering the numerators in the [OEIS](https://oeis.org).  However this reveals that the numerator of $a_{10}$ already has $97$ digits, so I don't like your chances of finding $a_{75}$.

Comment: With Python code: `a = [None] * 76
a[1] = 1
for i in range(2, 76):
    a[i] = a[i - 1] + 1 / a[i - 1]
print(a[75])` I have: $12.324223505191693$.